# Get latest record by grouping id

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table a has s_id,status_id,created_on columns.
Table structure - A:

```
s_id                       status_id     created_on
bbbef7457cf38d1e265955      54          2021-11-23 14:20:09
bbbef7457cf38d1e265955       5          2021-11-22 14:20:17
bbbef7457cf38d1e265955        1         2021-11-20 14:20:29
bbbef7457cf38d1e265955        7         2021-11-19 12:20:00
```

Another B table :

```
id  task             status
54  Mobile Number   SUCCESS
5   Mobile Number   FAILURE
1   Email           SUCCESS
7   EMail           Failure
```

i'm trying to pick lastest **created_on**  entered for task mobile number in table A

query i tried

```
select
    max (case when id = 5 or id=54 then created_on end) as mobileNumber
from A where s_id='bbbef7457cf38d1e265955'
```

Output expected

```
MobileNumber                             EMail
2021-11-23 14:20:09             2021-11-20 14:20:29
```

this didnt work as expected.

Comment: So you want to find latest created_on for each s_id from table A right?

Comment: why does your expected output contain two rows instead of one?

Comment: expecting lastest record for each status ,hence 2 rows @SalmanA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want lasted created_on by s_id, the query would be:

```
select
  s_id
  ,max (created_on) as mobileNumber
from A 
where s_id='bbbef7457cf38d1e265955'
  AND id in (5,54)
GROUP BY s_id
```